# Calculating the molarity of DNA in a cell

Tags: concentration, stoichiometry, mole

> In the following questions use a value of 3 for $\pi$, $6 \times 10^{23}$ for Avogadro’s number and $660$ for the molecular weight of $\pu{1 bp}$ of DNA. The volume of a sphere of radius $r$ is $4/3\,πr^3$. A bacterium has a single copy of a $\pu{4 \times 10^6 bp}$ circular genomic DNA.
>
> If the diameter of this spherical cell is 1 micrometer, what would be the molar concentration of DNA in this cell?

The volume comes to be $\pu{2 \times 10^{-5} L}$.
Amount of substance is $\pu{6.7 \times 10^-18 mol}$.
Dividing this by the volume, my answer comes $\pu{3.3 \times 10^{-13} M}$, but the answer given in my book is $\pu{3.3 \times 10^{-9} M}$.

Comment: Surely as a polymer of indeterminate length, the molar concentration of DNA is an entirely meaningless phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stated bacterium's cell has a diameter of $\pu{1 \mu m}$, the volume can be derived in terms of liters remembering the linear relation between cubic meters:
$$
  V_\text{cell}
    =\frac{4}{3}\pi \left(\pu{0.5\times10^-6 m}\right)^3
    =\frac{4}{3}\pi \left(\pu{0.5\times10^-5 dm}\right)^3
    =\pu{5\times 10^-16 L}
$$
Inside this volume, the organism contains a certain number of base pairs; so the total amount of substance has to be known.

From Avogadro's Number, a mole is defined to be that portion (number of particles) of every substance in a defined physical phase; since this is an aqueous solution, the volume, as well as the molecular weight is meaningless: if one mole is defined by a certain number of particles, a different number of particles defines a different amount of substance:
$$
  n_{\text{tot bp}}
  =\frac{N_{\text{bp}}}{N_{\text{A}}}
  =\frac{\pu{4\times 10^6 molecules}}{\pu{6\times 10^23 molecules mol-1}}
  =\pu{6.7\times10^-18 mol}
$$
Then, by the definition of molarity, dividing the amount of substance contained inside the cell by its volume gives a decent number, for a cell:
$$
  M_\text{DNA}
  =\frac{n_\text{tot bp}}{V_\text{cell}} 
  =\frac{\pu{6.7 \times 10^-18 mol}}{\pu{5 \times 10^-16 L}}
  =\pu{1.34 \times 10^-2 M}
$$
I think that the wrong result is due to the volume, because to me it seems rather surprising that one sphere of $\pu{1 \mu m}$ in diameter has:
$$
  \pu{2\times 10^-5 L}
  =\pu{2\times 10^-2 mL}
  =\pu{20 \mu L}
  =\pu{20 mm3} 
  \neq \pu{5 \times 10^-8 mm3}
$$
of occupied volume. I suspect that something went wrong with the conversions, because I don't see (for now) any errors in my derivation.

Comment: I found the mistake in my volume of 2X10^-5 L.

Comment: Although I cannot find any mistake in your calculation, your answer does not match the one given in my book !

Comment: @biogirl My suggestion is to tell your professor about this mistake, show the calculation proposed and let him give you the correct advice. Maybe you should take the problem *backwards* with the given result: since the volume calculation *is* correct, there should be something missed with the moles. I'll try by myself and edit my answer if any breakthrough comes up.

Answer (score 2):

There is one particle of dsDNA in the cell. Divide by $N_\mathrm{A}$ to get the amount of substance, and divide by the volume to get the concentration matching the concentration given in the answer.

\begin{align}
  V_{\mathrm{cell}} 
    &= 4 \cdot {(\pu{0.5 μm})}^{3}\\[0.5ex]
    &= \pu{0.5 μm3}\\[0.5ex]
    &= \pu{5E-16 L}\\[3.5ex]
  N_{\mathrm{A}}
    &= \pu{6E23 1//mol}\\[3.5ex]
  n_{\mathrm{DNA}} 
    &= \frac{1}{N_{\mathrm{A}}}\\[0.5ex]
    &= \pu{1.7E-24 mol}\\[3.5ex]
  c_{\mathrm{DNA}}
    &= \frac{n_{\mathrm{DNA}}}{V_{\mathrm{cell}}}\\[1.5ex]
    &= \frac{\pu{1.7E-24 mol}}{\pu{5E-16 L}}\\[1.5ex]
    &= \pu{3E-9 mol//L}
\end{align}

Comment: @Martin Nice vertical alignment, but what about the vertical space? OK, I looked it up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228609

Comment: Keep in mind that MathJax only borrows a small subset of commands from (La)TeX, the complete overview is in the documentation: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros/. Manual spacing is not always a good idea, but in this specific situation it's perfectly fine, because MathJax tends to look different depending on the locally installed fonts. Maybe also interesting (loads of MathJax = slow): [Hidden points of editing you probably didn't know](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3054/4945)